# State a necessary and sufficient condition for a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$ has precisely one basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

State a necessary and sufficient condition for a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$ has precisely one basis.

I tried solving this problem as follows:

Let $\dim V=n.$ So, we can assume, $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ to be a basis for $V.$

Let $c\neq 0$ be in $F.$

Claim: $cB$ is a basis for $V.$

This can be verified easily. Suppose $c_1,...,c_n$ be scalars such that $\sum _{i=1}^nc_icv_i=0\implies cc_1=cc_2=...=cc_n=0\implies c_1=c_2=...=c_n=0$ as, $c^{-1}$ exists.

Now, for $x\in V$ $\exists b_1,...,b_n\in F$ such that $\sum _{i=1}^nb_iv_i=x=\sum _{i=1}^nb_ic^{-1}(cv_i).$ Thus, $x\in \text{span}(cB)\implies V\subseteq \text{span}(cB)\implies V=\text{span}(cB),$ as $\text{span}(cB)\subseteq V.$

This proves our claim.

As, $B$ is the only basis for $V$ so, $cB=B$ is the only possibility. This implies that every element in the basis can be expressed as a non-zero scalar multiple of another element in the same basis.

We note that, $c\neq 0$ is an arbitrary non-zero scalar of $F.$ So, if  $V$ has only one basis then every element in the basis can be expressed as a non-zero scalar multiple of another element in the same basis.

---

But I don't understand whether the converse of this statement holds as well, i.e, "If every element in a basis of a vector space $V$ can be expressed as a non-zero scalar multiple of another element in the same basis, then $V$ has precisely one basis."

If this converse statement holds, then I am having a hard time proving this as well. Any help regarding this question will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $\{v_1+v_2,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is another basis of $V$. Therefore, if $V$ has exactly one basis, then $\dim V<2$.
If $\dim V=1$ and $v\neq0$, $\alpha\in F$ and $\alpha\neq0,1$, then $v$ and $\alpha v$ are  different bases.

Hence, if $V$ has precisely one basis, then $\dim V=1$ and $|F|=2$. The converse is obvious.

PS. The empty set is sometimes thought to be the basis of the null space. In this case it is necessary to change the formulation.

Here we go:

If $V$ has precisely one basis, then  either $\dim V=1$ and $|F|=2$ or
$\dim V=0$ and $F$ is an arbitrary field.
The converse is still obvious.